# loopback model validation failures (asynchronous behavior)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, loopbackjs

I'm trying to validate a model and it's contents.  However, because of the structure of loopbacks custom validation functions it's quite difficult to program more advanced logic than simple string validation.

```
Job.validate('job_definition, function(err){
    //err();
    //this will succeed in throwing error
    Job.app.models.anotherModel.findOne({where:{name:this.job_definition.toolName}}, function(error, tool){
      if(tool.aProperty === this.job_definition.aProperty){
          //err();
          //this will not succeed, validation script will exit before err() is thrown
      }
    });
}, {message: 'this is malformed'});
```

How can I get this validation function to 'wait' before exiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using validateAsync (https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#validatable-validateasync). Note that you have to run err() when you want to fail validation.

```
module.exports = function(Person) {

    function myCustom(err, done) {
        console.log('async validate');
        var name = this.name;
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(name == 'Ray') {
                err();
                done();
            } else {
                done();
            }

        }, 1000);   
    }

    Person.validateAsync('name', myCustom, {message:'Dont like'});

};
```

Does this make sense? FYI, I could rewrite that if a bit nicer.

Comment: Actually, that will make the problem worse as the validation will be passed over and resolved at some other time.  I'm just wrapping the model creation in a more complex validation and creating the model in the validation callback.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you then. If your validation logic *must* be async, doesn't that imply you must use this form?

Comment: The validation methods provided by loopback don't allow for advanced validation because they will always exit at the end of the function without waiting for a return (or cb()).

Comment: That's not the issue though. From what I see, validate() requires you to return a response. You can't use async code. You can do something custom here, something complex, but it must be sync. If you need async validation, you use the async version instead.

Comment: Just an FYI, I got a working example of this - I'm at a conference so it might be a few hours, but I believe I have a good answer for you. It took me a bit to figure out.